Unexpected behavior after writing class-based Apps Script code
I've been having a problem with class logic pattern in my google apps script project, and I'm not sure if it's my logica, .gs file arrangement, or if this is just unexpected behavior with classes in the google V8 engine.  Nonetheless, I cannot figure out why this code won't run. It's a google apps script project attached to a spreadsheet:
(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/120mXQ5v4XtBeUQGAv57WkXuFhZBGwn6mywEY5vGU_Nw/edit?usp=sharing)
For context, I am trying to understand dependency injection and coupling. I created a class, "TocSheet.gs" that manages a table of contents, and of course relies on Spreadsheet App for functionality as well as PropertiesService to store the state of a TocSheet instance. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, the link is available to the public. To access the code, click Extensions > Apps Script. Thanks for any help you can offer.
Localized issue:
In the TocSheet.gs file, you will see that I'm attempting to inject two
"dependencies" into the class TocSheet constructor as parameters (spreadsheet App: new SpreadsheetUtil() and propsService: new PropertiesServiceStorage()). The execution log for some reason shows that the SpreadsheetUtil object was loaded into the spreadsheetApp variable and I'm not sure why.
UiManager.gs
class UiUtil {
    constructor(spreadsheet) {
        this.uI = spreadsheet().getUi();
    }

    alert(message) {
        return this.uI.alert(message);
    }

    createMenu() {
        return this.uI
            .createAddonMenu()
            .addItem("Insert", "start")
            .addSeparator()
            .addItem("Remove", "confirmDelete")
            .addToUi();
    }

    confirmDelete() {
        const response = this.uI.alert(
            "Confirm Deletion",
            "Delete this item?",
            this.ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL
        );

        if (response) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.uI.alert("Deletion Cancelled");
        }
        return false;
    }
}

function start() {
    const uI = getSpreadsheetApp().getUi();
    const sheet = undefined; //JSON.parse(getPropsService().getScriptProperties().getProperty("sheet"))
    //console.log("sheet from props service: ", sheet)
    if (!sheet) {
        const spreadsheetApp = new SpreadsheetUtility();
        const propsService = new PropertiesServiceStorage();
        const myToc = new TocSheet(spreadsheetApp, propsService);
        uI.alert("sheet created");
        console.log(myToc);
    }
}

// function setFalse(){
//   const doSort = false
//   const tocSheet = new SheetManager("TOC", getSpreadsheetApp, getPropsService,getScriptApp);
// }

function confirmDelete() {
    const isConfirmed = Ui.confirmDelete;
    if (isConfirmed) {
        removeToc(isConfirmed);
    }
}

SpreadsheetUtility.gs
class SpreadsheetUtility {
    constructor() {
        this.activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    }
    insertSheet(name) {
        return this.activeSheet.insertSheet(name, 0);
    }

    setNamedRange(name, range) {
        this.activeSheet.setNamedRange(name, range);
    }

    getSheets() {
        return this.activeSheet.getSheets();
    }

    getSheetByName(name) {
        return this.activeSheet.getSheetByName(name);
    }
}

function myFunction() {
    console.log(new SpreadsheetUtility().getSheets());
}

PropertiesService.gs
class PropertiesServiceStorage {
    constructor() {
        this.key = "tocSheet";
    }

    save(tocData) {
        const data = JSON.stringify(tocData);
        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(this.key, data);
    }

    load() {
        const data = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(
            this.key
        );
        if (!data) {
            return null;
        }
        return JSON.parse(data);
    }
}

TocSheet.gs
    class TocSheet {
  
  constructor(name, titles, spreadsheetApp, propsService){
    console.log("From Toc: Spreadsheet: ", spreadsheetApp, propsService)
    this.state = {};   
    this.state.name = name || "Table of Contents";
    this.spreadsheetApp = spreadsheetApp || new SpreadsheetUtility();
    this.propsService = propsService || new PropertiesServiceStorage();
    this.state.properties = {
      sheetId: null,
      titles: null,
      range:{
        headerName: "TOCHeader",
        tocName: "TOC"
    }}
    this.initialize();
  }

  static load(){
    const storage = new PropertiesServiceStorage();
    storage.load();
  }

  initialize(){
    this.createSheet();
    this.setSheetId();
    this.setTitles();
    this.setNamedRanges();
    //setTitleLinks();
  }


  createSheet(){

    console.log("name",this.state.name)
    const sheet = this.spreadsheetApp.insertSheet("Table of Contents")
    this.sheet = sheet;
  }

  setSheetId(){
    this.state.properties.sheetId = this.sheet.getSheetId();
  }

  setTitles(titles = null){
    if(titles){
      this.state.properties.titles = titles
    }else{
      const sheets = this.spreadsheetApp.getSheets();
      const titles = sheets.filter(title => title.getSheetId() !== this.sheetId);
      this.state.properties.titles = titles;

    }
  }

  setNamedRanges(){
    const rangeHeader = this.sheet.getRange(1,1)
    const numRows = this.state.properties.titles.length;
    const rangeToc = this.sheet.getRange(2,1,numRows)
    this.spreadsheetApp.setNamedRange(this.state.properties.range.headerName, rangeHeader)
    this.spreadsheetApp.setNamedRange(this.state.properties.range.tocName, rangeToc)
  }

}


you have two methods named setNamedRanges  in TocSheet.gs

I've split your code into "files" for you ... and fixed your sometimes random indentation - should be more readable now

Ok, thank you for that!  I apologize for the indentation, I was having trouble pasting the code here.  Also, I've update TocSheet.gs, restructured the properties in the constructor, and removed the duplicate setNamedRanges method.  Again, thank you for that catch.  Also, were you able to reproduce the issue in which the propsService data is loaded into spreadsheetApp?

@JaromandaX - Again thank you!  After removing the duplicate setNamedRanges instance method and making modifications to the structure of TocSheet class constructor instance properties, the code is now running as expected!  I greatly appreciate the insight!

Silly me, I'm sure I had to have been tired or something. The issue was that the constructor in TocSheet.gs accepts 4 arguments constructor(name, titles, spreadsheetApp, propsService). I make a call to TocSheets by creating a TocSheets instance object in the UiManager.gs file where I only pass two arguments:   const myToc = new TocSheet(spreadsheetApp, propsService);.  This shift to the left results in the incorrect loading of variables, in this case, undefined values for spreadsheetApp and propsService in the TocSheet.gs file.
